# How to set data type for money in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to php & mysql..& i want to store money in database like **45,000** or **21,000** ....

Right now I am using datatype **decimal(50,2)** , But it shows only 45 when i put 45,000...

If i put 45000 ...then it results ok.......But I want to put 45,000 like this...

what datatype should i use...so it display currectly??

If i use **varchar(50)**, then i cant sort that data...thats the problem....

Please give suggestion..

Thanks

Comment: Storing it is a decimal is fine, but you should do your formatting after retrieving the value in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
 <?php
 function money($value) {
     return "$".number_format($value);
 }

 $money = 2000.00;

 echo money($money);

 // returns $2,000.00

 ?>
```

use below function

```
$amount = '100000';
$amount = moneyFormatIndia( $amount );
echo $amount;

function moneyFormatIndia($num){
$explrestunits = "" ;
if(strlen($num)>3){
    $lastthree = substr($num, strlen($num)-3, strlen($num));
    $restunits = substr($num, 0, strlen($num)-3); // extracts the last three digits
    $restunits = (strlen($restunits)%2 == 1)?"0".$restunits:$restunits; // explodes the remaining digits in 2's formats, adds a zero in the beginning to maintain the 2's grouping.
    $expunit = str_split($restunits, 2);
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($expunit); $i++){
        // creates each of the 2's group and adds a comma to the end
        if($i==0)
        {
            $explrestunits .= (int)$expunit[$i].","; // if is first value , convert into integer
        }else{
            $explrestunits .= $expunit[$i].",";
        }
    }
    $thecash = $explrestunits.$lastthree;
} else {
    $thecash = $num;
}
return $thecash; // writes the final format where $currency is the currency symbol.
}

// output 1,00,000
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/ptxvrU

Comment: @yogesh....thanks, that worked for me very well....but now when i am entering 1,39,000 ..it shows 139,000...but i want is 1,39,000.

Comment: @Dev See edited answer. And the money_format() will not work if u r using windows machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just use use `decimal(10,2)` field type and use [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php) in PHP

Comment: Thanks alienwebguy, but not taking the function "money_format()"

Comment: Not taking it? What do you mean? You might need to set your locale. Read the docs.

Comment: I have set it, but it shows error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function money_format()"

Comment: Ah you're on WAMP? You're a rare breed :) OK Use Yogesh's `money()` function to replace it and you should be fine.